# Android: What do the users do with my app?

Tags: android, behavior

In order to create a sustainable Android App, I want to capture, how the users are actually using it. Why improving a feature that is actually not really being used?
So I would like to collect anonymous data on different user actions. For example send data whenever a user clicks button XY.
So to my question: Does anybody know, whether there is already a framework or a service out there, that would support me on this purpose, or do I have do implement everything from scratch?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: use fabric/firebase to observer user iteractions and other infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some 3rd party libraries for that purpose. Some of them are given below:

- [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)
- [MixPanel](https://mixpanel.co)
- [Flurry](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/)
- [APSALAR](https://apsalar.com/)